# Thread Safe Bounded Priority Queue in java

Tags: java, priority-queue

is there any library that implements a thread safe bounded priority queue in java?
I need something like quava's MinMaxPriorityQueue except being thread safe.
if the queue is full it should remove the element with the lowest priority and add the new element except when new element is the one with the lowest priority.

Comment: yes but it does not remove the element with lowest priority if new element with higher priority is added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make MinMaxPriorityQueue synchronized

```
 Queue<E> queue = Queues.synchronizedQueue(MinMaxPriorityQueue.<E>create());
```

Queues is part of com.google.common.collect package.